# Space after macro \@percentchar

Tags: shell-escape

I am trying to call ImageMagic to crop my pictures. I send command to system with `\write18`, and I need to use percent symbol into my command line. Can't use "`\%`", but `\@percentchar` works almost good. Almost because it ignore all the spaces after macro and within lines:

```
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{start cmd echo /k magick convert _SDC2664.jpg  -crop 50\@percentchar x100\@percentchar +repage _SDC2664.jpg}
\makeatother
```

I get an error

```
"convert: invalid argument for option '-crop': 50%x100%+repage @ error/convert.c/
ConvertImageCommand/1210."
```

So, I need a space, " ". Make `"50%x100%+repage"` into `50%x100% +repage`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `\@percentchar\space` work?

Comment: Hi, the last paragraph of the [question that was marked a duplicate on your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547008/passing-a-percent-symbol-to-the-windows-console) states "Note that spaces behind macros are removed also in a `\write` statement, so you might need to manually insert one using `\space`." Did you miss it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\@percentchar\space`

(A good question is: why is `\@percentchar` only an internal command? The more-available `\percentchar` is defined in doc.dtx.)

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own command

```latex
\makeatletter
\edef\wpercent{\@percentchar\space}
\makeatother
```

and use

```latex
\immediate\write18{start cmd echo /k magick convert _SDC2664.jpg  -crop 50\wpercent x100\wpercent +repage _SDC2664.jpg}
```

If you don't plan to pass the command line as an argument to another command, you can do

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\magick}{\begingroup\catcode`\%=12 \@magick}
\newcommand{\@magick}[1]{\immediate\write18{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\magick{start cmd echo /k magick convert _SDC2664.jpg  -crop 50% x100% +repage _SDC2664.jpg}
```

(your editor’s syntax coloring might be upset by this, as you see, add `\magick` to the list of verbatim-like commands).

If your conversions use exactly the same parameters, you can do it in an easier way:

```latex
\providecommand{\magick}{}% to check it's not defined
\begingroup\catcode`\%=12
\gdef\magick#1{start cmd echo /k magick convert #1 -crop 50% x100% +repage #1}
\endgroup
```

and then simply call `\magick{_SDC2664.jpg}`

Is it possible without `\gdef`? Yes:

```latex
\begingroup\lccode`?=`\% \lowercase{\endgroup
  \newcommand{\magick}[1]{start cmd echo /k magick convert #1 -crop 50? x100? +repage #1}
}
```

which exploits the fact that there is no uppercase character in the “parameterized” command line. This won't affect uppercase in the argument at call time, because `\lowercase` is only executed at definition time.

Comment: Hmmm... why I can't do like this: 
\newcommand{\magick}{\begingroup\catcode`\%=12 \@magick}
\newcommand{\@magick}[1]{\immediate\write18{start cmd echo /k magick convert #1   -crop 50%x100% +repage #1}\endgroup}

\magick{ _SDC2664.jpg}

Comment: @Vladimir You can certainly do it, if all conversions have the same parameters. I added this to my answer.